# How to fetch custom user entity for custom authentication in login on spring security?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to set up a custom authentication and custom user entity with spring security. How do I setup the configuration right, so that UserRepository would be able to pull the user information from the database?

I have seen some spring tutorials on how to make a custom user entity to authenticate and login with, instead of using the spring security default. I am not sure if the problem is in the configuration of spring security or is the problem with the mapping of user and authorities. Here is the configuration, controller --> UserDetailsService --> Repository, entities and sql tables.

Spring Secutrity configuration

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.mithrandir.springcrud")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl successHandler;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider
          = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/add/**").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/updateProduct/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/delete/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/doLogin")
                .successHandler(successHandler)
                .successForwardUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/doLogout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll()
            .and()  
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
    }

}
```

LoginController login POST request

```java
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String postLogin(Model model, HttpSession session) {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder
                .getContext().getAuthentication();
        validatePrinciple(authentication.getPrincipal());
        User loggedInUser = ((UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUser();

        model.addAttribute("currentUserId", loggedInUser.getId());
        model.addAttribute("currentUser", loggedInUser.getEmail());
        session.setAttribute("userId", loggedInUser.getId());
        return "redirect:/";
    }

        private void validatePrinciple(Object principal) {
        if (!(principal instanceof UserPrincipal)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Principal can not be null!");
        }
    }
```

AuthenticationSuccessHandler to update last online date

```java
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        userRepository.updateLastLogin(new Date());
    }

}
```

UserDetailsService

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        System.out.println("UserDetailsService, user from db: " + user);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with email: " + email);
        }
        return new UserPrincipal(user);
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```java
    @Override 
    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query<User> query = session.createQuery("FROM User u WHERE u.email=:email", User.class);
        query.setParameter("email", email);

        System.out.println("UserDAO: finding user by email");
        return query.uniqueResult();
    }
```

UserPrincipal:

```java
public class UserPrincipal implements UserDetails  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 777221850757925972L;
    private final User user;

    public UserPrincipal(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getAuthority().toString()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
    // getters and setters through the user field
}
```

User entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7630269547387051923L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;

    @Column(name = "accountNonExpired", nullable = false)
    private boolean accountNonExpired;

    @Column(name = "credentialsNonExpired", nullable = false)
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;

    @Column(name = "accountNonLocked", nullable = false)
    private boolean accountNonLocked;

    @Column(name = "creationDateTime")
    private Date createDateTime;

    @Column(name = "updatedDateTime")
    private Date updateDateTime;

    @Column(name = "lastOnlineDateTime", nullable = false)
    private Date lastOnline;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_authorities",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id") })
    @Fetch(value=FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<Authorities> authorities = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {

    }
     //... getters and setters
```

Authorities entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "authorities")
public class Authorities implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5383739733021126813L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AuthorityType authority;


    public Authorities(AuthorityType authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }
    //... getters and setters
```

AuthorityType enum:

```java
    public enum AuthorityType {
        ROLE_ADMIN,
        ROLE_MANAGER,
        ROLE_USER
    }
```

And finally here is the sql schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id` BIGINT(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `firstName` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `lastName` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` CHAR(76) NOT NULL,
    `enabled` TINYINT NOT NULL,
    `accountNonExpired` TINYINT NOT NULL,
    `credentialsNonExpired` TINYINT NOT NULL,
    `accountNonLocked` TINYINT NOT NULL,
    `creationDateTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `updatedDateTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `lastOnlineDateTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `authorities` (
  `id` BIGINT(19) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `authority` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `user_authorities` (
  `user_id` BIGINT(19) NOT NULL,
  `authority_id` BIGINT(19) NOT NULL,
  KEY `user` (`user_id`),
  KEY `authority` (`authority_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `authority` FOREIGN KEY (`authority_id`) REFERENCES `authorities` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is the output i get from console when first entering the right credentials:

```java
UserDAO: finding user by email
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_3_, user0_.accountNonExpired as accountN2_3_, user0_.accountNonLocked as accountN3_3_, user0_.creationDateTime as creation4_3_, user0_.credentialsNonExpired as credenti5_3_, user0_.email as email6_3_, user0_.enabled as enabled7_3_, user0_.firstname as firstnam8_3_, user0_.lastname as lastname9_3_, user0_.lastOnlineDateTime as lastOnl10_3_, user0_.password as passwor11_3_, user0_.updatedDateTime as updated12_3_ from user user0_ where user0_.email=?
Hibernate: select authoritie0_.user_id as user_id1_4_0_, authoritie0_.authority_id as authorit2_4_0_, authoritie1_.id as id1_0_1_, authoritie1_.authority as authorit2_0_1_ from user_authorities authoritie0_ inner join authorities authoritie1_ on authoritie0_.authority_id=authoritie1_.id where authoritie0_.user_id=?
heinäkuuta 10, 2019 5:10:40 IP. org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.LoadContexts cleanup
WARN: HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@67b156c6<rs=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet@3fe5ce85 [wrapping: null]>
heinäkuuta 10, 2019 5:10:40 IP. org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext cleanup
WARN: HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [1] entries
```

When trying to login with invalid credentials:

```java
UserDAO: finding user by email
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_3_, user0_.accountNonExpired as accountN2_3_, user0_.accountNonLocked as accountN3_3_, user0_.creationDateTime as creation4_3_, user0_.credentialsNonExpired as credenti5_3_, user0_.email as email6_3_, user0_.enabled as enabled7_3_, user0_.firstname as firstnam8_3_, user0_.lastname as lastname9_3_, user0_.lastOnlineDateTime as lastOnl10_3_, user0_.password as passwor11_3_, user0_.updatedDateTime as updated12_3_ from user user0_ where user0_.email=?
UserDetailsService, user from db: null
```

So I can see that repository can find the user from the database, but for some reason can't pull it out... Is the mapping wrong or the configuration? Thank you beforehand for putting your time to help!

Comment: in your method `UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername` returned type _UserPrincipal_, what is this? is it your own custom class?

Comment: @Anthony Yes it implements the UserDetails of spring security. Sorry, I forgot to put the code of it in here, it should be up there now.

Comment: Do other variables like `accountNonExpired  and etc` exist in your implementation? Did you try to use implementation of`org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.java`?

Comment: Yes i have the all the required variables. Eclipse generates the methods to be overwritten when implementing an interface. I have looked at the out of the box User class of spring security, but i saw tutorials where it was done this way so i gave it a try. I will refactor the code to make my UserPrincipal extend the User of spring security and see what i get.

Comment: Could you add additional info in logger about result of UserRepository.findbyemail method. Does it return correct obj?

Comment: Well it does not return anything... It fails on the query.uniqueResult(); in the UserRepository if an entry is found in the database.

Comment: Why did you use _email_ in `UserDetails loadUserByUsername()` instead of _username_ ? [UserDetailService javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html)

Comment: Because I want the user to login using email instead of username. I mean it's just the name of a variable inside this method so it should not matter if its called "username" or "email", because the repository still pulls the data by matching email.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand how do you map your Authorities(AuthorityType) to your authorities table. Try to add @Column(name = "authority") to field AuthorityType

Comment: Mmm that is right, I have forgotten to put the column annotations on both id and authority... Before I make the refactor to extend spring securitys provided User.class I will try by adding the columns to the authority. Hopefully I have time to make it today.

Answer (score 0):

I have established what you want with complete java configuration without any xml.

1.) I guess your security config is not correct. Don't use the @ComponentScan annotation because this class is neither your root onfiguration class nor your servlet configuration. Simply delete this line.

2.) You must tell the antmatcher what to do. Like this:

```
.antMatchers("/administration/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
```

because you want to grant access for this url.

3.) I'm not sure but can you check if the Authorities are really granted to the user if the credentials where ok? I'm using spring and have something like this in my UserDetailsService:

```
if (user != null) {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorites = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    for (Iterator<UserUserroles> i = user.getRoles().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        UserRole role = i.next().getRoleid();
        authorites.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    }

    SpringSecurityUser securityUser;
    securityUser = new SpringSecurityUser(user, authorites);
    return securityUser;
} 
throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
```

I manually add the roles of a user as an Authority. Maybe your solution is smarter but check if this part is working.

Comment: I started by taking away the annotation of ComponentScan and the thing spit out a 404. I forgot to put the UserPrincipal class in the question, it has the method "getAuthorities()" that returns a collection of GrantedAuthorities, like you have made in the service layer. I will make my UserPrincipal as your securityUser and see what comes out of it. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah still the same... I'll put it back as it was.

Comment: So you are sure that the right roles are granted to the user. Ok. What about the antmatcher?